# create signals in a custom QSlider class

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

I'm new in Qt and I'm trying to create a custom `QSlider` class (it inherits from `QSlider`).
This works perfectly but when I try to create new signals and slots, it doesn'ts work. Actually, I think it's the `Q_OBJECT` macro which doesn't work... Indeed, I get this message from the compiler :

`erreur : 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 
erreur : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

If I remove `Q_OBJECT` it doesn't work either as the compilers tells me :

`erreur : Error: Class declaration lacks Q_OBJECT macro.`

Finally, if I make my class inherit from `QWidget`, all is working even the `Q_OBJECT` macro...

Here is my `.h`  code :

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QSlider>

class mySlider : public QSlider
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit mySlider();

signals:
    void test();

public slots:
    void nTest();
};
```

Here is my `.cpp` code (there isn't much things, I'm only trying to make this simple code work for now) :

```
#include "myslider.h"

mySlider::mySlider()
{

}

void mySlider::test(){

}

void mySlider::nTest() {

}
```

Comment: Don't write an implementation for signals, only for slots.

Comment: Also, although not relevant in the context of your question, `#include <QWidget>` is not necessary, since _QSlider_ is a subclass of _QWidget_.

Comment: you mean it's impossible to create your own signals ?

Comment: Define "custom `QSlider`", Qt classes are very customizable without use of inheritance.

Comment: @Seth You can declare them in your header file but should not define them in you cpp, they are not intended as functions, that is what slots are for